# Mega.nz download doesn’t save

Tags: download, mega

I downloaded a cinematic pack from MEGA.nz and opened it and played it in my video player. However, after I got done watching it. It deleted itself from quick access and I can’t find it. Does that mean I wasted 2 hours downloading something or is it saved somewhere on my hard drive? I don't think I clicked save after the download or I forgot.

Comment: If it isn’t saved I’ll just redone load it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading from MEGA.nz is a bit tricky because it can look like you download it twice but in fact, you download it into a MEGA.nz "buffer" and then from your browser to your local drive. In your case, it depends on what you did... some browsers can provide "open file" without saving it locally. In such case, the file is opened (in video player) and removed from your temp folder on video player closure.

Your only chance is to download it again from buffer **if you did not close that browser tab**. If you did, then you are good to go downloading it again for 2 hours

Comment: I used Microsoft edge as my browser, I have a recovery software called ease us data. can I just scan my temp folder and recover it. That takes less time then currently waiting and 1hour and a half more.UGH

Comment: @NRSJ you can try, but in most cases are recovered files corrupted so good luck

Comment: Thanks for the help I’ll use redownload

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and saved the files again by doing the below tricks.

1. scan your OS drive with any file checking tool like windir
2. We can easily find the location for the temp file from this
3. Open this file with the same browser which you are used to downloading the file
4. It will prompt for a save option.. please go-ahead